# php after 5 characters replace text?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of text ike

Lets say

`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.`

And I want to make it so if a word is longer then 5 characters it replaces the characters with +. So that string would become

`Lorem Ipsum is simpl+ dummy text of the print+++ and  types++++++ indus+++. Lorem Ipsum has been the indus+++++ stand+++ dummy.`

But I don't want to include punctuation such as ! and , and . but I do want to include apostrophes '

Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
         industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.";
echo preg_replace("/(?<=[\w']{5})[\w']/", '+', $text);
```

which will output:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simpl+ dummy text of the print+++ and types++++++
             indus+++. Lorem Ipsum has been the indus+++++ stand+++ dummy.
```

Comment: Good call on the positive lookbehind. This is a much more elegant solution that the one using the callback function.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
function callback($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . str_repeat('+', strlen($matches[2]));
}
$str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.";
$str = preg_replace_callback("#([a-z']{5})([a-z']+)#i", 'callback', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: You could change your preg to `preg_replace_callback("#(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\s]/]{5})/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\s]/+)#", 'callback', $str);` to allow for all letters/numbers

Comment: @manyxcxi, "*Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 41*". I'll leave deciding what ranges of characters to include to author, I just wanted to show a basic example. I added `i` modifier though. If talking about "how else it could be done", I like @Bart's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this

```
$str =  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
         typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
         standard dummy.";

$pattern = "/([a-zA-Z]{5})([a-zA-Z]+)/";
$newStr = preg_replace($pattern,"$1+",$str);

echo $newStr;
// the + added
```

you have to test this as i dont have php on this machine

Comment: It just trims every word to max 5 characters, e.g., `typesetting` is replaced with `types` rather than `types++++++`.

Comment: you are right i forgot the plus sign, but will still only add one + sign.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use strtr()

```
preg_match_all('/[\w\']{5}[\w\']+/', $s, $matches);
$dict = array();
foreach($matches[0] as $m){
    $dict[$m] = substr($m, 0, 5).str_repeat('+', strlen($m) - 5);
}
$s = strtr($s, $dict);
```